# Constructor of react component is called twice

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react app which includes a websocket. Now I wondered why the websocket connection is always opened twice when I open the react app once.

After some investigation I found out that it actually my root component 'App' which is somehow constructed twice. I have in my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And in App.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.ms = new MessageHandler('ws://localhost:3000/ws');
    console.debug('Component App is constructed');
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <!-- Boring content -->
        </div>
            )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Now when I load the app I always get two on connection calls on the websocket server and the console also shows 'Component App is constructed' twice.
Accordingly, for some reason, react seems to call `new App()` (or whatever is similar to this in react framework) twice and I have no idea what to search for. Any ideas? Or at least any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to React [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).  From the docs:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
>       Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
>       Function component bodies
>       State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
>       Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Just remove the `<React.StrictMode>` tag in index to avoid this.  Hope that helps!

EDIT:  On a related note, if you are doing something when the component is mounted, such as async data retrieval, consider moving that logic out of your constructor to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function.  You can read about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it. I also read about using componentDidMount, but I also use the websocket in child components, registering listeners there, therefore componentDidMount was called to late for my purpose.